# Create a phoenix function for use in spirit rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I'm trying to make the code below compile, but, as usual, errors with spirit/phoenix gives not a lot a clues about what is wrong. Can anyone see what the problem is ?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>


typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> sptr;


struct bar
{
    template <typename A> struct result
    {
        typedef sptr type;
    };

    template <typename A> sptr operator()(A) const
    {
        return sptr();
    }
};


boost::phoenix::function<bar> foo;


void test()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using qi::_val;

    qi::rule
    <
        std::string::const_iterator,
        sptr(),
        boost::spirit::ascii::space_type
    >
        test_rule = qi::eps [ _val = foo() ];
}
```

Comment: You've declared `bar::operator()` as taking a single argument, but you're calling `foo` with no arguments...

Comment: @ildjarn does not work better without argument in `operator()`.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/oBBqD$0

Comment: Thx this is it. I was really close to the solution... It's a shame compilation errors are not helpfull.

Comment: @neodelphi : They are if you use clang... ;-]

Comment: By the way, do you know if this can be achieve with boost::pheonix::actor instead of function ? I used to use boost::phoenix::actor before but I can't understand what is the difference ?

Comment: @ildjarn [indeed](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2sERjd$0).

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah its impressive. g++ should do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ildjarn said, call to foo misses an argument.